# Iterate over list of methods and take the first non null response

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have three functions. Input and output parameters of all three functions are same.

Let's say

```
public void String function1(String abc, String xyz);
public void String function2(String abc, String xyz);
public void String function3(String abc, String xyz);
```

I have a caller function which is implemented like

```
public void String callerFunction(String abc, String xyz) {
     String output = function1(String abc, String xyz);
     if(output == null) { 
          output = function2(String abc, String xyz);
     } 
     
     if(output == null) { 
          output = function3(String abc, String xyz);
     } 
     return output;
}
```

While this code works, what's the best way to write this kind of logic, i may want to add a new function4 also in the future.

One way that comes in my mind is

```
public interface functionInterface {
      public String fetchValue(String abc, String xyz);
} 

public class function1Class {
      public String fetchValue(String abc, String xyz) {
         // return some string.
      }
} 

public class function2Class {
      public String fetchValue(String abc, String xyz) {
         // return some string.
      }
} 

public class function3Class {
      public String fetchValue(String abc, String xyz) {
         // return some string.
      }
}


public void String callerFunction(String abc, String xyz) {
     List<functionInterface> flist = new Arraylist<>();
     functionInterface f1 = new function1Class();
     functionInterface f2 = new function1Class();
     functionInterface f3 = new function1Class();
     flist.add(f1);
     flist.add(f2);
     flist.add(f3);
     
     String output = null;
     for(functionInterface f : flist) { 
         output = f.fetchValue(abc, xyz);
         if(f.fetchValue(abc, xyz) != null) {
            return output;
         }
     }
     return output;
}
```

- Is this over engineering ?
- Is there a better way to handle this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

The coalesce() function is the public function which will evaluate all functions passing the 2 parameters.

`evaluateFunctions` iterates over all passed functions and returns the first non-null result. If tomorrow you have a new function4 just add it to the method call.

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

private String function1(String abc, String xyz) { return null;};
private String function2(String abc, String xyz) { return "2";};
private String function3(String abc, String xyz) {return "3";};

private String evaluateFunctions(String param1, String param2, BinaryOperator<String>... functions)
{
    for(BinaryOperator<String> fun:functions)
    {
        String value=fun.apply(param1, param2);
        if (value!=null)
            return value;
    }
    return null;
}

public String coalesce(String param1,String param2)
{
    return evaluateFunctions(param1,param2,
            (p1,p2)->function1(p1,p2),
            (p1,p2)->function2(p1,p2),
            (p1,p2)->function3(p1,p2));
}
```

What you define as public or private depends on where you want the decision to be made. `evaluateFunctions` can even be made generic so it works for all kinds of functions which have 2 parameters of the same type:

```
private <T> T evaluateFunctions(T param1, T param2, BinaryOperator<T>... functions)
{
    for(BinaryOperator<T> fun:functions)
    {
        T value=fun.apply(param1, param2);
        if (value!=null)
            return value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

BinaryOperator<T> = BiFunction<T,T,T>: a function where the 2 parameters and the return value are all of the same type. (Thanks @jaco0646)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, what's meaning of `(p1,p2)->function1(p1,p2)`? What can i search on google to learn more about this syntax

Comment: You could use [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) in place of `BiFunction`.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal  `(p1,p2) -> function1(p1,p2)` is a [Lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Java stream's laziness to do this. In the following, not all functions are invoked when one of them already returns a not null result:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    BinaryOperator<String> f1, f2, f3;
    f1 = (a, b) -> {
      System.out.println("Calling f1");
      // your logic here
      return null;
    };

    f2 = (a, b) -> {
      System.out.println("Calling f2");
      // your logic here
      return "222";
    };

    f3 = (a, b) -> {
      System.out.println("Calling f3");
      // your logic here
      return "333";
    };

    String a = "aaa";
    String b = "bbb";

    String ret = Arrays.asList(f1, f2, f3)
                       .stream()
                       .map(f -> f.apply(a, b))
                       .filter(v -> v != null)
                       .findFirst()
                       .get()

    System.out.println(ret);
  }
}
```

By providing the functions as an array, you can add new function any time.

Java fiddle to play with on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@lini/Java-Stream-Laziness)